# Customize existing menu/toolbar Item

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I am building a netbeans platform application. This application is project based. I need to customize existing menu/toolbar items.

For instance, when a java project is selected, the "New File" button on the toolbar brings a standard wizard. But when a custom project (my project type) is selected, I would like that same button to bring my own dialog/wizard.

How do I achieve this?

I have been struggling with this for quite some time, any pointer would be greatly appreciated.